# How many blocks have to be read until the data block for inode N can be read

Tags: inode

How can I calculate the amount of blocks I need to read before I can read a specific data block of a given inode?

Examples:

1. I want to read block 7 of the the file which is referenced by inode 3
2. I want to read block 1000 of the file which is referenced by inode 3

For 1. I guess I could directly read inode 3 from the disk to then read the 7th direct data block which are 2 read operations.

For 2. I would need to read a double indirect data block which gives me a total of 4 read operations.

Is this correct?